# Выделение памяти для одномерного массива

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

```
short *massTempOld = new short[*size];
for (short i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    massTempOld[i] = mass[i];
delete [] mass;
(*size) += (*sizeTemp);
short *mass = new short[*size];
for (short i = 0; i < *size; i++)
{
    if (i < (*size - *sizeTemp))
        mass[i] = massTempOld[i];
    else mass[i] = massTemp[i];
}
delete sizeTemp;
delete [] massTemp;
delete [] massTempOld;
```

До свитча выделяется память для массива `mass[size]` и генерирую элементы.
В одном из кейсов я создаю массив `massTempOld[size]` в который записываю элементы `mass[size]`, после чего удаляю память `delete[]mass` и выделяю по этому же указателю память на заданный размер больше `(*size) += (*sizeTemp)` → `short *mass = new short[*size];` и записываю туда старые +новые элементы. После выхода из свитча на экран выводится мусор из массива `mass[size]`. Подскажите в чем проблема. Спасибо!

Comment: Вот интересно, откуда ноги растут у этой странной, но устойчиво повторяющейся манеры заводить промежуточный временный массив, когда надо перевыделить основной массив. Постоянно устойчиво встречается это штампованное бессмысленное "переливание" данных туда-сюда. Ясно, что это идет из какой-то "методчики". Что это за методчика?

Comment: Что такое `delete sizeTemp;`? У вас что ли одинокая переменная в динамической памяти выделена была? Зачем? Что такое `massTemp`, откуда он взялся и какой размер он имеет?

Comment: чем плох std::vector?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, я почти уверен, что это какая-то лаба. У нас на первом курсе можно было использовать только C-подмножество С++, нельзя было использовать std::cout и тому подобное. Аргументировалось это тем, что мы должны представлять, как это работает на низком уровне. Вот только никто не объяснил, почему printf понятнее std::cout. Один препод вообще на пятом курсе потребовал писать программы без использования std::vector и аналогов (там нужна была абстракция для математических векторов). Пришлось писать свой класс на основе `unique_ptr<T[]>`. Java и C# программисты негодовали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... и выделяю по этому же указателю память ...

По какому такому "этому же указателю"? У вас в коде объявляется *совершенно новый* локальный указатель `mass`

```
short *mass = new short[*size];
```

который не имеет никакого отношения к исходному указателю `mass`.

Память, указываемую исходным указателем `mass` вы освободили

```
delete [] mass;
```

и больше этот исходный указатель `mass` вы не трогали вообще. Т.е. этот исходный указатель `mass` так и остался указывать "в никуда" (на освобожденную память). Дальнейшее поведение при доступе через этот `mass` не определено. У вас получился просто мусор на экране, а могло быть и хуже...

P.S. См. также мой комментарий под вопросом. Зачем вам понадобилось создавать промежуточный массив `massTempOld` - не ясно.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Я только учусь поэтому строго не судите. С указателем разобрался. А вот каким образом можно перевыделить основной массив без потери данных, которые там лежали?

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть массив `mass` размером `size` и стоит задача (ручного) перевыделения памяти с поэлементным копированием данных, то для этого не нужно создавать лишние временные массивы. Достаточно выделять память под новый размер `size2`, перенести в неё все данные из старого массива, после чего удалить старый массив, а новый можно переназначить на старый указатель:

```
int* mass2 = new int[size2];    // выделяем новую память
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)  
   mass2[i] = mass[i];          // копируем старые данные
delete [] mass;                 // удаляем старый массив 
mass = mass2;                   // переназначаем указатели
```

Для дополнительной защиты можно обнулить указатель `mass2`:

```
mass2 = 0;
```

Этим мы как бы говорим, что он уже не владеет данными и защищаемся от случайного освобождения памяти повторно вызовом `delete [] mass2`. Вызов `delete` на нулевом указателе - безопасен и просто ничего не делает.